# How do I make a loop that runs through every value in a list, printing each value in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, char

How do I make a loop that runs through every value in a list, printing each value in a C# console application?

I understand how to make a loop, but I don't get how it would be done using a list. Its a char list.

Comment: @ 53 Answers posted and only 30 answers selected. 0 (ZERO) votes!!! Really?

Comment: I suggest to google for answers before asking a question. A google search for this question title and the first 2 links are to SO, the third MSDN How to: Create a C# Console Application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx#Y2560. This page answers the question more than adequately.

Comment: @CharithJ Jacob asked a 200 bounty question. Until the question expired with my answer alone with 7 votes, he didn't respond to me at all. So I ended up 100 rep. And he just accepted my answer after 3 days. I gotta thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than with any other type of list.

```
List<char> theList = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
foreach (char theChar in theList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(theChar);
}
```

Comment: Also note that you could replace the entire loop with `theList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` if you preferred.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also in that way...

```
        List<char> _myCharList = new List<char>();
        _myCharList.Add('a');
        _myCharList.Add('b');
        _myCharList.Add('c');
        _myCharList.Add('d');

        for (int i = 0; i < _myCharList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_myCharList[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

is the same result as the answer above